# Form auto submit jquery

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form which action is set to a link , http://website.co.za/blablabla

and I have a js script to auto submit it on page load and NOT redirect it to the form action url.
but it doesnt work , pls help.

My Code:

The following code will make it auto submit on page load BUT it loads the page to the form action URL and it should not redirect.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#myform2").submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: When you .submit a form, it will always load the page you submit to.  You could use ajax to submit the data without loading the form's action url.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $.post($("#myform2").attr("action"), $("#myform2").serialize());
});
```

Comment: Weird, because you are not "get"ting anything.  You should use post.  However changing it from $.post to $.get is pretty easy.

Comment: @James How do you know what the form is for? It's perfectly ok to use GET in forms. It's common in e.g. search forms so that the user can bookmark the result page.

Comment: @Juhana Well the nature of the question is to send data to the server without wanting/displaying a response.

Answer (score -1):

You opened a parenthesis, so close it.

```
$(function(){
    $("#myform2").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: this also doesnt work , stays on page after load but form not submitted to action

Comment: Consider doing your research before you ask a question. It literally provides a search bar right there before you ask a question telling you to research. Here you go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694653/jquery-submit-form-without-page-reload

Comment: that link describes it as when you click a submit button, i dont have a button it is auto submit...